# What are alarm gems used for?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

After completing an event quest, I received some alarm gems. I looked through my consumables inventory but they're not there.

What can these alarm gems be used for?

Answer (score 1):

These are used for the in-game alarm clock function.

You don't have to use gems to use the alarm clock itself, but you can purchase new voices with the gems.

The alarm clock maybe be accessed through the menu with the gear icon, located in the top right of the town screen.

Have some fun, wake up to your waifu! :>

[image: Alarm screen]

Comment: word of warning. The alarm function is _extremely_ finicky, so don't rely on it if you need a reliable alarm to wake up to.